# What are the standards for binding pleadings? Staples? Paper clips?

Tags: rules-of-court, paperwork

When submitting pleadings to a court, normally there are two pieces: a court-provided cover sheet and the pleading itself. What is the normal way to connect these pieces of paper?

(1) staple everything together

(2) staple the pleading but attach cover sheet with paper clip

(3) paper clip everything together loose

Comment: Binder clip it?

Comment: No idea. Lawyers haven't filed pleadings in paper format in the jurisdictions where I practice for something like a decade. The federal rule governing pleading format is FRCP 10 and in states that follow that model state rule of civil procedure 10 would often supply an answer.

Comment: Might try calling the clerk's office and asking. They can't give legal advice but probably would answer this question.